# How to access the second element that has the same class name

Tags: java, selenium

When trying to automate our application, there are two buttons with the same name.

I'm not able to find a way to recognize these. Please let me know what could be the any ways to identify these elements in selenium webdriver in java

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the application under test? If not, can you share more information on the buttons? Specifically the resulting HTML for each?

Answer (score 3):

Use either the xpath or css (preferred) to locate the required button as below.

Let's consider the below sample html.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
  <button class="same_class">follow</button>
  <button class="same_class">follow</button>
</body></html>
```

Now you can use the css with <kbd>nth-of-type</kbd> as shown below

```
button.same_class:nth-of-type(2)
```

**CSS Screenshot:**

[image]

You can achieve the same with xpath too.

```
(//button[@class='same_class'])[2]
```

**XPath Screenshot:**

[image]

<kbd>change the index in parenthesis as required (index starts with `1` not 0)</kbd>

Comment: Excellent examples

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array while constructing XPath for the element.
If there are two button elements with the same class name on UI. e.g. 
`.//*[@class='XYZ']`

So, if above XPath identifies two elements, you can locate first with (`.//*[@class='XYZ']`)[1] and second with (`.//*[@class='XYZ']`)[2]

Let me know if this resolves your query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tags defined as follows in DOM:

```
<button name="foo">foo</button>
<button name="foo">foo</button>
```

You can match whatever button you want using XPath [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function

- 1st button: `//button[@name='foo' and position() = 1]`
- 2nd button: `//button[@name='foo' and position() = 2]`

The benefit of using `position()` function is that browser stops looking for further matches so instead of finding all buttons and filtering them to the required one it will find the button with the given position and stop reducing execution time and resource requirements.

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)